# Node.JS - How to hide secrets such as cookie secrets?

Tags: node.js

I would like to avoid having secrets hard coded into my Node.JS application like this:

```
app.use(cookieParser('SECRETSECRETSECRET1!!!'));
```

How can I secrets in Node.JS?

Comment: asking for "best practices" is seeking opinion. Don't say "best practice" here.   But asking "how can I..." and then explaining that you do not want this secret to be burned into your source code for security reasons is a much better way to phrase the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep them in your `.env` file.

Then you can use packages like [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) to load them into your js code

**Update**

As mentioned @Wyck, you should add `.env` to your `.gitignore`, since you don't want to make your env variables to be visible in your public/private repo

Comment: A few more details are worth spelling out explicitly.  Don't commit your .env file (add it to your .gitignore, for example).  In a production environment, the secret would be passed in as an environment variable, accessed with `process.env.MY_COOKIE_SECRET`. In a development environment you'd add `MY_COOKIE_SECRET=SECRETSECRETSECRET1!!!` to your local .env file.